# conversion of fraction value of time format in r

Tags: r

In my excel file time is in the time format like below

10:42:37
10:43:55
10:45:13

But when I importing that time in r I am getting like below

"0.446261574074074"
"0.447164351851852"
"0.44806712962963"

My code is as below

```
df <- read.xlsx("F:/data/filename.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1, header=F)
datirow       <- c(seq(1, a[1], by = 12))
daytime <- df[datirow,2]
```

So later I have tried the below code to convert fraction time to time format by the below code

```
dddd<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric((daytime)), origin = "2019-08-02 10:42:37",tz="GMT")
```

So I am getting

2019-08-02 10:42:37
2019-08-02 10:42:37
2019-08-02 10:42:37

i.e time remains the same as origin time. It is not changing with time step.
So how to resolve it. I am looking forward to your help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`POSIX` times are based numbers of seconds - for example, you can see all of these are 1 second apart:

```
as.POSIXct(c(1, 2, 3), origin = "2019-08-02 10:42:37",tz="GMT")
# [1] "2019-08-02 10:42:38 GMT" "2019-08-02 10:42:39 GMT" "2019-08-02 10:42:40 GMT"
```

Looks like the Excel format is based on number of days. So we need to convert your decimal days to seconds and set the origin time to midnight:

```
daytime = c("0.446261574074074",
"0.447164351851852",
"0.44806712962963")

as.POSIXct(
  as.numeric((daytime)) * 24 * 60 * 60,
  origin = "2019-08-02 12:00:00", tz="GMT"
)
# [1] "2019-08-02 22:42:37 GMT" "2019-08-02 22:43:55 GMT" "2019-08-02 22:45:13 GMT"
```

Comment: Thanks @Gergor Thomas

Comment: I have tried with ``` as.POSIXct(
  as.numeric((daytime)) * 24 * 60 * 60,
  origin = "2019-08-02 ", tz="GMT"
)```.  Then I am getting right answer but date is not changing from 2019-08-02 to 2019-08-03. How to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you have inputs where the date should be different? Is there anything different in the input that shows where the date should change? Maybe ask a new question, showing example data that should fall on different dates.